# problems with Boto3 upload data

Tags: python-3.x, object, amazon-s3, upload, boto3

I'm parsing data from a NMEA data on a tcp socket and I have to store it into a S3.
once parsed the data I have to create a json file to be stored into the bucket.

```
      #!/usr/local/bin/python
      import boto3
      import jsoncode



#initialization
client = boto3.client('s3')
bucketS3='mybucket'
keyS3='myfolder/myfile..json'
serverIP='192.168.10.219'
serverPort=3000
```

[...]

```
if fields[0]==b'$GPRMC':
print ('cmd $GPRMC received!', file=sys.stderr)
msg={}
msg['Long']=fields[5]
msg['Lat']=fields[3]
msg['Spd']=fields[7]
msg['Hdg']=fields[8]
msg['Date']=timeStamp

json_object = (json.dumps(msg.decode("utf-8"))
client.put_object(Body=json_object, Bucket=bucketS3, Key=keyS3)
```

But it retuns the error:

```
File "/home/myaws/awsS3/myscritpt.py", line 78
  client.put_object(Body=json_object, Bucket=bucketS3, Key=keyS3)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Entire code is not even a valid python because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```py
json_object = (json.dumps(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

has 3 open brackets "(" but only 2 close brackets ")".

You should remove the bracket at the front:

```py
json_object = json.dumps(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```